# Show/hide Div when select option value

Tags: javascript, php

When echo inside value the javascript onchange doesnt work. it must click/choose again to show the div.

```
<?php
$test = '1'; 
?>

    <select name="request" id="reqtypev" class="form-control1" >
    <option value="<?php echo $test ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $test ?></option>
    </select>
```

it does work if you didnt echo it using php.

```
//javascript
      $('#reqtypev').change(function(){
        if( $(this).val()==="1" || $(this).val()==="2" || $(this).val()==="3" || $(this).val()==="4" ){
        $("#otherTypev").show()
        } else {
         $("#otherTypev").hide()
        }
    });
```

how is it possible to execute the javascript when you echo using php ?

Comment: value in option at least 2 values function activity() to action.

Comment: Seems to me the logic should be `if (this.selectedIndex > 0) ...` then you can have an unlimited number of options and only show the div if an option other than the first one is selected (assuming that the first is the default selected with text like "Please select…"), or even `$('#reqtypev').change(function(){$('#otherTypev')[this.selectedIndex > 0?'show':'hide']()})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger change event after page load for #reqtypev as following:

```
(function ($) {

    $(function () {
        $('#reqtypev').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val()==="1" || $(this).val()==="2" || $(this).val()==="3" || $(this).val()==="4" ){
                $("#otherTypev").show()
            } else {
                $("#otherTypev").hide()
            }
        });


        $('#reqtypev').trigger("change");
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for this it must trigger to show the div. very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$test = '1'; 
?>

    <select name="request" id="reqtypev" class="form-control1" onchange="intializeDrop(this.value);" >
    <option value="<?php echo $test ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $test ?></option>
    </select>
```

Js code:

```
function intializeDrop(id){
    if( $(this).val()==="1" || $(this).val()==="2" || $(this).val()==="3" || $(this).val()==="4" ){
        $("#otherTypev").show()
    } else {
        $("#otherTypev").hide()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//javascript
  $(document).on('change','#reqtypev',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="1" || $(this).val()==="2" || $(this).val()==="3" || $(this).val()==="4" ){
    $("#otherTypev").show()
    } else {
     $("#otherTypev").hide()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't think it's doable in PHP, PHP executes once and quits (Until another refresh occurs)

You can do it in PHP, once.  But not live where people are moving the selection bar around.

Can you put more info on what you want to do?  I assume from the little code you are showing is to hide a field in the form once a person chooses a value < 1 or > 4

Answer (score 0):

Value in option at least 2 values function change() to activity

```
<div id="otherTypev">texttttt</div>
<select name="request" id="reqtypev" class="form-control" >
  <?php 
    for($i = 0;$i<=10;$i++){
      echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
  ?>  
</select>
```

Js

```
<script>
   $('#reqtypev').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val()=== "1" || $(this).val()==="2" || $(this).val()==="3" || $(this).val()==="4" ){
       $("#otherTypev").show()
    } else {
      $("#otherTypev").hide()
    }
 });
</script>
```